# Filtering and order by option to view questions

Tags: support, questions, filtering, question-lists

How to filter unanswered questions with up votes ordered by newest ? Is this a feature request in SO ?

At present I can view `newest`, `featured`, `frequent`, `votes` and `active` tab. If I choose `votes` tab, I can see question starting from most upvotes. What I want is filtering the result with unanswered and order by newest.

This will help me to see the unanswered questions with most upvotes asked recently. If I can answer it I will submit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using a custom search.

[Example on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0%20score%3a1).

You have to search for `answers:0` (question has no answers) and `score:1` (has at least a score of 1) and then sort on the `newest` tab.

Comment: is there any documentation available for this. This is the first time seeing this in SE

Comment: Yes, there is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching